# Getting distorted Images after capturing from camera in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera

This issue is not 100%. This is producing rarely when i start capturing images from camera and tap on done button images gets distorted.

here is image refrence:

[image]

I have debug this issue to get resolved but didnt get any clue for this.